# How does Stack Overflow access my details

Tags: discussion, support

[image]

When I click this [button](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla?tab=profile) on Stack Overflow site, it shows all my details correctly. But I never provide these details to Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange.

So my question is

1. How do they access this?
2. What are the benefits for me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you have registered on SO Careers some time ago. That is how they got that data. Maybe this was imported using the LinkedIn sync.

From their [FAQ](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> **I have a LinkedIn profile. Can it be imported?**
>
> Yes! You can import your LinkedIn profile in just three clicks. Go to your profile and in the right hand column you can choose to “import linkedin”. From there just log into LinkedIn and you’re all set.